# cocoa pods not working

Tags: swift, cocoapods

I have a newly created project, which I used

> pod init

on to initialize cocoa pods

Im adding a single pod ([TCPickerView](https://github.com/ChernyshenkoTaras/TCPickerView) ) to it and trying to use it but getting errors

podfile:

```
    # Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Symphony' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'TCPickerView'

  # Pods for Symphony

  target 'SymphonyTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'SymphonyUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

I do

> pods install

then open the Symphony.xcworkspace file and build

Then I add the example code from the [TCPickerView](https://github.com/ChernyshenkoTaras/TCPickerView) site  (see second screenshot which shows code and errors).

screenshot showing the pods library is included in the Symphony project
[image]

screenshot with code and error
[image]

Comment: make sure you have added `import TCPickerView` after `import UIKit` in `class ViewController`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem with your podfile, I tried it works, I guess you are missing `import TCPickerView`

It goes right after `import UIKit` in `class ViewController`

Answer (score 1):

Can you update your pod file

```
    platform :ios, '9.0'
    use_frameworks!

    target 'Symphony' do

      pod 'TCPickerView'

      target 'SymphonyTests' do
        inherit! :search_paths
        # Pods for testing
      end

      target 'SymphonyUITests' do
        inherit! :search_paths
        # Pods for testing
      end

end
```

and try like this and reinstall pods again : `pod install`

Usage: `import TCPickerView`